# Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF -exec rm -rf {} \

Tags: perl

I have a script that deletes files older than 90 days

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
system("find /home/user/data -type f -mtime +90 -exec rm -rf {} \");
```

when I run the above with `perl script.pl` I get this:

```
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at test.pl line 4.
```

I used to run it with `-exec rm -rf {} +` but now I want to run `-exec rm -rf {} \` in my script.

Comment: For some reason you are escaping the closing quote of the system string with a backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` doesn't produce `\` in a double-quoted string literal, but `\\` does.

```perl
system("find /home/user/data -type f -mtime +90 -exec rm -rf {} \\");
```

---

That said, `-exec rm -rf {} \` isn't valid. `-exec` is terminated by `;` or by `+`, not by `\`.

Of course, `;` is special to the shell, so we need to escape as follows:

```bash
find /home/user/data -type f -mtime +90 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

As we learned above, we can use the following double-quoted string literal to achieve this:

```perl
"find /home/user/data -type f -mtime +90 -exec rm -rf {} \\;"
```

---

But what's the point of invoking a shell here?

```perl
system(
   find => (
      "/home/user/data",
      -type => "f",
      -mtime => "+90",
      -exec => (
         rm => ( "-rf", "{}" ),
         ";",
      ),
   )
)
```

---

But what's the point of invoking `find` here?

```perl
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

for my $qfn (
   File::Find::Rule
   ->file
   ->mtime( ">=".( time - 90*24*60*60 ) )
   ->in( "/home/user/data" )
) {
   unlink( $qfn )
      or warn( "Can't unlink `$qfn`: $!\n");
}
```